# libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__XML_SetUserData

Tags: svn

Getting linker error while building subversion 1.7.8 libsvn_ra-1.dll on vc 6.0.

I have include XML_STATIC in pre-processor directive in project settings and used MFC shared dll.

```
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol     
  __imp__XML_SetXmlDeclHandler
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
  __imp__XML_SetUserData
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
  __imp__XML_SetCharacterDataHandler
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
  __imp__XML_SetElementHandler
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol  
  __imp__XML_ParserCreate
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
  __imp__XML_ErrorString
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
  __imp__XML_GetErrorCode
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__XML_Parse
  libneon.lib(ne_xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol  
  __imp__XML_ParserFree
  ..\..\..\\Release\subversion\libsvn_ra\libsvn_ra-1.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 10  
  unresolved externals
  Error executing link.exe.
```